# O que acontece quando uso using namespace dentro de um namespace?

Tags: c++, namespace, using, scope

O que acontece quando uso a diretiva `using namespace x` dentro de um `namespace`?

Por exemplo:

```
namespace x {
int k = 1;
}

namespace y {
using namespace x;
}
```

Agora quando eu usar o `namespace y` consigo acessar definições do `x` também? Isto é:

```
namespace z {
int c = y::k;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O segundo código funciona e acessará o valor de `k`. O `using` acaba sendo uma espécie de *include* no escopo, ainda que não funcione igual ao `#include`, que até passa ter menos utilidade no C++20, já que este último traz o texto e o `using` apenas permite referência.

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace).